# Problems with logs

Tags: android, logcat

Problems with logcats
When run the program, appears the  error

I think that the problem of data transmission by using Intent

Please help me

Thats my logcats

```
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life.BrainUpgrade}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life.BrainUpgrade.onCreate(BrainUpgrade.java:29)
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)

11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
11-15 19:45:16.614 3369-3369/com.example.admin.upgrade_your_life E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thats my code:

```
public class BrainUpgrade extends AppCompatActivity  {

    TextView text1;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    int i;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.brain_upgrade);


        boolean checkbox1;

        checkbox1 = checkbox.isChecked();
        if (checkbox1){
          i = 1;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("checkbox",i);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){

    }
}
```

Comment: You have a NPE at line 29 of BrainUpgrade. We can't help without your code.

Comment: You have NullPointerException! It means that you use an object which is null. It is occur in BrainUpgrade activity(Maybe you use a view that never find it by findViewById).

Comment: Thats my code. See in description

Answer (score 0):

```
    checkbox1 = checkbox.isChecked();
```

this won't work until you assign checkbox to something. For example, you set an id in your brain_upgrade.xml layout:

```
 <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox"></checkbox>
```

and then in your code you find the checkbox by this id:

```
    checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    checkbox1 = checkbox.isChecked();
```